# Is the react state meant to be used within the component it is defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, react-props

Should react component state is meant to be used in the component in which it is defined?
I faced a scenario, where a component state is updated by two different components and is passed as a prop to its child. But never used in the component where it is defined.

For example: I have a component **CommonComponent** which has a state, 'stateObj' and it has two child components **ChildComponent** and **ModifyComponent**.
I have one more component, **CreateComponent** which is a parent of **CommonComponent**.

I have two cases here:

1. During create action, **CommonComponent** receives props from **CreateComponent** and updates the state- 'stateObj' and is passed as a prop to **ChildComponent**
2. During modify action, **ModifyComponent** updates the state of **CommonComponent** using a callback and in turn the 'stateObj'
   is passed as a prop to **ChildComponent**

Is this a valid way of using the component's state? As I understood, The state is meant to be used by its component in which it is defined. But, here I am not using the 'stateObj' in **CommonComponent**. but, i am just using it to send data to its child components. Am I using the state in a right way? or is there any other way of doing this?

your suggestions are really precious!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The state does not have to be only in current component. Let s say we do not have redux. Then, You have to use a parent component like reducer which manages the state and passes down as a prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the state to CreateComponent instead of having it in CommonComponent. So, ModifyComponent and CommonComponent will have callback props which will update the state in CreateComponent.